# Mutable reference to parent in tree-like structure

Tags: rust, tree, immutability, borrow-checker, mutable

I am developing a Rust program that performs operation on tree structures, let's call them `Node`. It is not required to store list of child nodes of each node, but it is needed to be able to get back to parent node from any other node. Assuming immutable structure, the `struct Node` could look like this:

```rust
struct Node<'a> {
    parent: Option<&'a Node<'a>>,
    // ... node attributes ...
}
```

The problem is that I need to change the tree. I have a function that receives a leaf node and performs changes on the tree (only changing node attributes, never the tree structure). It needs not only to change leaf node attributes, but also to change attributes of node's parent.

It could look like this:

```rust
fn mutate_tree(leaf: &mut Node) {
    leaf.attr1 = 42;
    leaf.parent.unwrap().attr1 = 43;
}
```

How can I design the `struct Node` to allow these modifications (and getting a mutable reference to parent nodes)?

I am always traversing the tree from the deepest level up, not in the opposite direction.

The `Node`s get instanced in functions that also destroy them. I am trying to find solution that does not require them to be heap-allocated, but if it is not easily possibly, I could live with allocating all nodes using `Rc`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, probably no, but I will take look at that. Also note that I want to store the references only in the child→parent direction.

Comment: You don't store references from the parent to the child? If so, it is not related.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, no, I need to store only the references to parent, I am always traversing the tree from the deepest level up.

Comment: Added more information.

Answer (score 0):

As multiple childs have the reference to the same parent, you need [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html):

```rust
struct Node<'a> {
    parent: Option<&'a RefCell<Node<'a>>>,
    // ... node attributes ...
}

fn mutate_tree(leaf: &mut Node) {
    leaf.attr1 = 42;
    leaf.parent.unwrap().borrow_mut().attr1 = 43;
}
```

Comment: This struct declaration won't work because it uses `'a` in an invariant position, just like `&'a mut Node<'a>` would (invariance arises from mutability, interior or not), and constructing the tree will fail. [Playground demo.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b8b72680f607293662e747f3aed4b398) Perhaps put only the attributes inside the `RefCell`, so the parent relationship stays immutable and covariant?

Comment: @KevinReid If the nodes are all constructed in one function it'll work. And prefer putting the attributes in `Cell` (if possible) to `RefCell`.